# Drawing a partially transparent density polygon

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density

How can I make this red polygon partially transparent so I can see the points underneath it?

```
library(ks)
set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(1000) + -150
y <- runif(1000) +   20

my.data <- data.frame(x,y)
my.matrix <- as.matrix(my.data)

my_gps_hpi <- Hpi(x = my.matrix, pilot = "samse", pre = "scale")

my.fhat <- kde(x = my.matrix, compute.cont = TRUE, h = my_gps_hpi,
               xmin = c(min(my.data$x), min(my.data$y)),
               xmax = c(max(my.data$x), max(my.data$y)),
               bgridsize = c(100, 100))
my.contours <- c(75)

contourLevels(my.fhat, cont = my.contours)
contourSizes(my.fhat, cont = my.contours, approx = TRUE)

plot(my.data$x, my.data$y)
plot(my.fhat, lwd = 3, display = "filled.contour", cont = my.contours, add = TRUE)

png(file="transparent_polygon_June21_2021.png")
     plot(my.data$x, my.data$y)
     plot(my.fhat, lwd = 3, display = "filled.contour", cont = my.contours, add = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a way to add transparency to a color, but I do not see where the color is specified. The simplest way would be to use the second plot command first after removing the add=TRUE argument so that the plot is drawn with the filled contour. Then add `points(my.data$x, my.data$y)` to put the points on top.

Comment: @dcarlson Thank you.  That does indeed work.  Although, I would also like to modify the color of the polygon.

Comment: The manual page for `?plot.kde` is silent on how to specify the color(s) for a `filled.contour` plot. The 'col.cont=' argument does not work and 'col.fun=' allows a function to be specified, but none of its arguments . Your best bet would be to contact the package maintainer: `maintainer("ks")` "Tarn Duong <tarn.duong@gmail.com>".

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a solution by digging around in the source code in the file `kde.R`.

I made several changes to my code.

1. Changed `my.fhat` to `fhat` because the source code might want `fhat`.
2. Changed `my.contours` to `contours` for the same reason.
3. Changed `contourLevels(my.fhat, cont = my.contours)` to `hts <- contourLevels(fhat, cont = contours)` for the same reason.
4. Extracted the `col.fun` from the source code and changed it to return the color of my choice: `col.fun <- function(n) {rgb(255, 0, 0, 127, maxColorValue=255)}`.
5. Modified the `plot` statement to that shown in the code below.

Here is the modified `R` code:

```
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/density_in_R/')

set.seed(1234)

library(ks)
x <- runif(1000) + -150
y <- runif(1000) +   20

my.data <- data.frame(x,y)
my.matrix <- as.matrix(my.data)

gps_hpi <- Hpi(x = my.matrix, pilot = "samse", pre = "scale")

fhat <- kde(x = my.matrix, compute.cont = TRUE, h = gps_hpi,
                xmin = c(min(my.data$x), min(my.data$y)),
                xmax = c(max(my.data$x), max(my.data$y)),
                bgridsize = c(100, 100))
contours <- c(75)

hts <- contourLevels(fhat, cont = contours)
contourSizes(fhat, cont = contours, approx = TRUE)

col.fun <- function(n) {rgb(255, 0, 0, 127, maxColorValue=255)}
col.fun(1)

plot(fhat, lwd = 3, display = "filled.contour", cont = contours, col.fun = col.fun(1), drawpoints=TRUE)

png(file="transparent_polygon_June22_2021.png")
      plot(fhat, lwd = 3, display = "filled.contour", cont = contours, col.fun = col.fun(1), drawpoints=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

[image]